# How to become a camera dealer for Canon/Nikon?

Tags: canon, nikon, business

I have a small studio. I want to sell DSLR cameras.

What criteria is there to become an authorized camera dealer for companies like Canon, Nikon?

Comment: May I ask why you want to sell new cameras? The retail side of camera sales are under huge pressure, local camera stores have been closing for years. Ritz/Wolf went bankrupt. The margins are very thin, and you have to compete with both Amazon and places like B+H and Adorama.  

Far too many people go to a local store to touch the camera and ask questions, and then go online because the price is a few dollars cheaper.   

It hard to make a buck at it. Most stores make all of their profit on accessories, not the bodies or lenses.

Comment: You should contact them directly! we can't answer on their behalf!

Comment: @Pat for a small studio owner, the real motivation might be getting their own equipment at wholesale prices and the reputation that comes with being "authorized", not actually making profit by selling a lot.

Comment: @imre, interesting speculation. I don't think the difference between wholesale to prices at places such as B+H or Adorama would be worth it. I could be wrong. I know in other businesses, such as the motor scooter business where I own a store, the franchise/brand has minimum yearly sales requirements to keep the deal. So you won't move enough for yourself to keep the deal.

Comment: I would recommend starting with used camera sales and see where that goes.  Do you have a good location?  Are you going to sell online?

Comment: I can't understand why you'd not just ask them...

Answer (score 4):

The requirements vary in different countries. There are local marketing offices for [Nikon Network](http://www.nikon.com/network/index.htm) and [Canon](http://www.canon.com/corp/list04.html); contact them to get the requirements and marketing materials in order to become authorized.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to have an established business and they may require you to stock a minimum amount of product.  You can contact Nikon or Canon direct (see Imre's answer) or contact a local Nikon/Canon distributor in your area.

There is an article [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_7592666_become-nikon-reseller.html) on becoming a Nikon reseller.